# How to delegate threads to multiple servers and keep a track in which thread is on which server using Java

Tags: java, multithreading, delegates, threadpool

We have a solution which runs on 13 servers. I wish to know how do we explicitly delegate threads to different servers and keep a track of which thread was on which server.

Comment: You will want to do some research into load balancing

Comment: Is it possible to do using Java, rather than F5. If not, how does java communicate with F5, any suggestion?

Comment: 1) Yes.  Do some research.  2) There are Java libraries available for (for example) iControl ... from the F5 site.  Do some research.

Comment: Generally speaking, this Question is way too broad to answer properly ... which is why nobody has attempted to do that.

Comment: ya. suggestions and research keywords would work for me as well. I need to know what to search. its impossible to make use of search engines without exact key words. It would be grateful if someone does atleast that much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application need to implement asynchronous event handling. One instance (node) of the application will trigger an event to another instance. On receiving the event, the second instance may decide what it should do. That way the thread on the first instance will delegate to a thread in the second instance. Once the second instance is done with the handling, it may notify back to the first instance. Not sure of the architecture of your product (messaging between multiple nodes, if there is any event handling mechanism which is already there etc).  You may like to check Node.js, Akka. But not really sure if that will work for you.

Comment: Thank you. Node management as in HADOOP maybe implemented in this situation where process delegation amongst multiple servers occurs via some api interconnecting them designed on Events and Observers model..